# Al insertar un nuevo dato desde Mysql no hay respuesta de mysqli_query o esta vacía

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, api

soy algo nuevo en php y tengo una pagina de usuarios y al usar mysqli_query me lista de manera correcta pero al insertar un nuevo usuario desde mysql la respuesta mysqli_query  es vació que podría estar pasando

```
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta)or die($conexion);
//var_dump($resultado);
while($registro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    
    $json['empresa'][]=$registro;
    echo $json['empresa'][];
    
}
```

Comment: Las sentencias INSERT no devuelven resultados, a lo sumo, puedes obtener el total de filas afectadas. Necesitarías otra consulta para obtener los registros guardados. Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega más información como para qué necesitas leer el resultado. Tal vez sea suficiente con obtener ID.

Comment: Como bien dice @Triby las sentencias `INSERT` no devuelven los datos que se han insertado a través de ellas, sino el estado de las mismas (true o false) si fueron exitosas o no y el número de filas afectadas. En cuanto a los datos, si los necesitaras para algo, los tendrías en ese contexto en las variables que usaste para hacer la inserción... es algo lógico. De todos modos la pregunta no es clara, ¿qué datos necesitas realmente?

Answer (score 0):

Como dicen los colegas: INSERT no devuelven datos lo que si te pueden retornar es si la acción se ejecuto de manera correcta, te recomiendo usar una variable de control con la cual retornar un mensaje de ejecución correcta el cual puedes capturar para hacer debug.

```
@$respuesta = (object)array();
if ($result=mysqli_query($conexion ,$consulta)){
$respuesta->value="Registro Guardado";
   }                       
else {
   $respuesta->value="Problemas al ingresar el registro, intenta nuevamente";
 }
echo json_encode(array("data"=>$respuesta));
```

Esta variable la puedes capturar en las herramientas de desarrollador WEB de Firefox o Chrome, ademas también la puedes usar en tu código a través de javascript para arrojar un mensaje en pantalla a través de ajax.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]